# Hiding browser popups - Watin

Tags: c#, popup, watin

I'm using Watin library in a windows forms app. In order to hide the browser I use this instruction :

```
Settings.Instance.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false;
```

However, it doesn't hide the popups (when simulating a click on an element that opens a popup).
Is there a way to hide them?

Comment: What kind of popups? Message boxes like alerts and confirms? or new windows opened with `window.open`?

Comment: new windows in fact

Comment: I got this working by injecting some javascript to the page loaded with Watin. Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it programmatically by running some javascript code and make `window.open` function to do nothing!

**Example**

[Here](http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/watin-disable-popups/) is a test page I made that has a very simple form and when the user clicks the *Sum* button, it sums up `numA` + `numB` and it displays the result inside a `<span id="result"></span>` element. After the result text update, it opens a popup window by calling `window.open`. In order to make this popup window disappear, we need to eliminate the `window.open` function:

```
window['open'] = function() { return false; }
```

To do that using Watin, we have to use the `Eval` function and inject the javascript code like this:

```
browser.Eval("window['open'] = function() { return false; }");
```

Then all popups are gone for that page load only and we have the wanted result.

**Sample C# code**

```
private void buttonPopupdEnabled_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    WatiN.Core.Settings.Instance.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false;
    IE ie = new IE();

    ie.GoTo("http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/watin-disable-popups/");
    ie.Eval("window['open'] = function() { return false; }");
    ie.TextField(Find.ById("numA")).TypeText("15");
    ie.TextField(Find.ById("numB")).TypeText("21");
    ie.Button(Find.ById("sum")).Click();
    string result = ie.Span(Find.ById("result")).Text;
    ie.Close();

    labelResult.Text = String.Format("The result is {0}", result);
}
```

**Program running before javascript injection (Popup shows up)**

[image: Popup without javascript injection]

**Program running after javascript injection (Popup is gone)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've checked [released notes](http://web.archive.org/web/20090301090755/http://watin.sourceforge.net/releasenotes-1-2-0-4000.html) and found this:

> By default WatiN tests make the created Internet Explorer instances
>   visible to the user. You can run your test invisible by changing the
>   following setting. **Be aware that HTMLDialogs and any popup windows**
>   will be shown even if you set this setting to false (this is default
>   behavior of Internet Explorer which currently can't be suppressed).

```
IE.Settings.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false; // default is true
```

Since `WatIN` haven't updated since 2011, I think you wouldn't expect any new feature support what you want.

I don't know if this could be a workaround but If those popups are not `important` to you why just don't block all popups?

[How to turn off popup blocker through code in Watin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934064/how-to-turn-off-popup-blocker-through-code-in-watin)

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_WEBOC_POPUPMANAGEMENT
Value = 0 for Off
Value = 1 for On
```

Comment: They are important indeed :/

Comment: @HediNaily Well, What you want is not provided by them. I think perhaps you must change your library.